# Ghostscript crashes the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, ghostscript, cassini

my problem is :  i am using ghostscript to transform some pdfs into jpeg files then render them into a silverlight control. I am transforming the pdf file using :

```
public void PdfToJpg(string ghostScriptPath, string input, string output) {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            //if the pdf has more than 1 file (ex. 3) then 3 jpeg files will be outputed 
            String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg  -r300 -o" + output + "-%d.jpeg  " + input;
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = ars;
            startInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;            
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }           
        }
```

then saving the page number and the page byte[]  into a dictionary, dictionary in a session and sending it with a silverlight enabled service, and sending them to aspx page that contains the silverlight control(with Response.redirect(page.aspx)). Everything works well but sometimes the server (Cassini or IIS) crashes, meaning that the files are converted but the redirection never occurs, simply the page stays in loading state. I have to close the cassini with "End Process" or Restart the IIS server so that the process to work again. I don't thinkthe problem is with the service because i have a similar process to send to the silverlight aplication a byte[] of audio file and everything works fine, the server never gets stuck, so i think it is because of ghostscript..., If anyone hassome ideas . Also i am using elmah and no error is reported... and when in debug when i click the view button which contains the converting and other parts of the process it doesn't enter the click event but the converting is done(not the redirect), i don't know how that is possible..., thanks. so for sure is something with ghostscript

UPDATE :
i changed my code to  :

```
     using (Process convertProc = new Process()) {
                convertProc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
                convertProc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
                //convertProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                //convertProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                convertProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                convertProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                convertProc.Start();
                ThreadedKill(convertProc.Id);
                convertProc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;
                convertProc.WaitForExit();
                }
```

and if the useshellexecute and redirectoutput are commented the server goes 'wild' sometimes and if not , the code runs perfect everytime, but with this the window from ghostscript process is appearing, i don't want that. To not appear i must comment thise lines or put useshellexecute to true and comment redirectoutput which is causing the failing sometimes. What can i do? and what is redirectStandardOutput and what it makes..., dind't understand on MSDN...

UPDATE 2 :
changed my gswin64.exe to gswin64c.exe for console application and now that window i was talking about isn't showing anymore. No code gone mad..., at least not yet..

Comment: To solve this you probably need to provide more specific information about the error, e.g. an exception with a stack trace or at least a Windows error code. What is logged in the event log?

Comment: this is the problem, no exception, no error in Event Viewer , nothing.., in TaskManager the gswin64.exe isn't running when the hanging occurs.

Comment: GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08) gswin64.exe

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need the `-dNOPAUSE` because the `-o` implies `-dBATCH` and `-dNOPAUSE` but it doesn't hurt.

Is this problem occurring 'intermittent'? Or if you send a file that hangs (crashes the server?) repeatedly: does it hang every time, or more frequently with that particular file?

If this is truly intermittent, it is unlikely to be Ghostscript.

To capture *stdout* and *stderr* from Ghostscript into files, you can add the `-sstdout=___.out` and `-sstderr=___.err` to see if Ghostscript has complained. If you always write the same files, the contents after the error will tell you if any messages were produced by gswin*.exe.

Adding `-Z:` will add some timing information to Ghostscript output as well.

Note that since you are using `-r300` for JPEG output: if Ghostscript is stopping unexpectedly, there will be two files in the *TEMP* directory that start with `te_` and have the `.tmp` extension. These are created for disk based 'clist' files used for banding (300 dpi letter size pages are large enough to exceed the default `-dMaxBitmap=____` value of 8m).

If you don't see an accumulation of `te_XXXXX.tmp` files in your TEMP folder, then Ghostscript is (probably) not crashing.

Comment: no 'te_'.tmp files in the TEMP directory..., it doesn't matter the file that i send, when it hangs, every file i send after that it doesn't work, it is converting to jpeg files but the rest of my code in codebehind doesn't get executed. And how the command should be ? :-sstdout=file.out -sstderr=file2.err  -sDEVICE=jpeg  -r300 -o" + output + "-%d.jpeg  " + input;, where the .err and .out files should be? can\t find them anywhere, or it is because gs doesn't produce errors? , now i found a pdf file that isn't transformed at all by gs and i think it should show some log or something ..., thanks